# Naming step definitions used with 2+ keywords (e.g. Given + Then)

Tags: cucumber, specflow, gherkin

Consider this feature snippet:

```
Given the date is '2022-01-01'
...
When the date is '2022-01-31'
...
```

One identical step but used with two different keywords. I haven't find much discussion about the naming convention in this case. I'd love for people to give their input.

The three main approaches I suppose are:

**Name method with first keyword you use**. If you need to use it again, just do it and ignore the fact that the method contains "Given" in its name

```
[Given(@"the date is '.*'")]
[Then(@"the date is '.*'")]
    public void GivenTheDateIs(string date)
    {
        ...
    }
```

**Use appropriate keyword in method name and create new method if needed more than once**

```
[Given(@"the date is '.*'")]
    public void GivenTheDateIs(string date)
    {
        //same code
    }

[Then(@"the date is '.*'")]
    public void ThenTheDateIs(string date)
    {
        //same code
    }
```

**Don't use keyword in method name**

```
[Given(@"the date is '.*'")]
[Then(@"the date is '.*'")]
    public void TheDateIs(string date)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Which one do you use and why?

Comment: This question is very subjective, and will likely get closed as opinion-based. I have run into this exact problem many times. My advice is to make this easy on yourself. Don't worry about the name. Your first suggestion works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
Given is for setting up state
When is for doing something
Then is for evaluating results
```

In English at least tense differentiates

```
Given - past tense
When - present tense
Then - future tense
```

Generally `When`'s are going to be done inefficiently.

With a UI a `When` will involve a browser interaction. Often a `Given` that does the same thing can be done more efficiently without that browser interaction. With an API the `When` will be done by a request/response cycle. Again a `Given` can do the same thing without the request/response.

For example consider adding the behaviour registration. First you would do

```
When 'I register' do
  fill_in name, with: "Fred"
  ...
  submit_form
end
```

But for you given you might do

```
Given 'I am registered' do
  User.create(
    name: "Fred"
    ...
  end
end
```

which is much much faster.

You will use `When I register` only a few times in your application

You will use `Given I am registered` (in some form or other) for almost every user interaction you write a scenario for.

For the above example the `Then` is

```
Then 'I should be registered' do
  # check UI for proof or registration
end
```

So `Given`'s, `When`'s and `Then`'s are not only different in their context and tense, but also they are different in their implementations and their frequency of use.

The idea that a `Given` could be identical to a `When` or `Then` just reflects a lack of understanding and precision in your use of language for your scenarios and code for the implementation of your step definitions.

Of course you are allowed to write Cukes without this precision and control, but you don't need to, and you will gain alot if can write precisely enough that you never have to worry about the difference between a `Given`, `When` or `Then`

Caveats: Answer is opinionated, but question is an excellent one in my opinion. All code and examples are Ruby. All the examples are crude and simplistic. Putting lots of code in step def and calling the database directly in test code is poor practice.